# COUNTIFS not working on date + time format

Tags: excel, date, time, format, spreadsheet

I have a table from which I need to count all values where in date range, is for examples less then.

Date Time format is: dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss

This is my current `COUNTIFS` code:

`=COUNTIFS(Data!Q:Q,"LDHL",Data!P:P,"<>916325",Data!O:O,"2020-12-16 22:30:00")`

It doesn't work because it can't read this date/time format? (`2020-12-16 22:30:00`)

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Change the format of Column O to Date Format

Comment: try to do `DATEVALUE("2020-12-16 22:30:00")` in the formula.. does it work?

Comment: is this excel or google sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am facing the same problem. I can come out with one solution for this case.

I removed the "hours" by using FLOOR:

`=FLOOR(Data!O,1)`

Then I use `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `COUNTIF`

`=SUMPRODUCT(1*(FLOOR(Data!O:O,1)=Data!A1))`

You can add more arguments by using asterix